# Prolog recursively checking if an item is in a list

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

So I am trying to write a piece of code that checks to see if an item is in a list or not.

```
is_member(_,[]).
is_member(X,[X|_]).
is_member(X,[_|tail]):- is_member(X,tail).
```

this is currently what I have for the code. It works if the item is in the first position but doesn't check the rest of the list. Can anyone help me figure out what i'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What about using the builtin [`member/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2) function

Answer (score 2):

Your predicates faces the following two problems:

- The base case `is_member(_,[]).` will always return true for an empty list, which is not correct; and
- Your variable should start with an **U**ppercase character: *Tail*.

An example how to implement a predicate that solves these two issues:

```
is_member(X,[X|_]).
is_member(X,[_|Tail]):- is_member(X,Tail).
```